# Java, I dont understand why this is happening, variable changes

Tags: java, variables, random, methods

```
    public void askForDate(Scanner in) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the date that the vehicle entered the car park in this format dd/mm/yyyy :");
    String enteredDate = in.nextLine();

    //This array will hold the 3 elements of which the date is made up of, day, month and year, and this method returns it.
    String[] dateEnteredSplit = enteredDate.split("/");

    //I am using the split method to seperate each number, which returns an array, so I am assigning that array to the dateEnteredSplit array.
    //dateEnteredSplit = enteredDate.split("/");
    //So now the first element holds the day, second the month, and the third element holds the year.

    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dateEnteredSplit));

    //Assigning each element and converting them to integers.
    int day = Integer.parseInt(dateEnteredSplit[0]);
    int month = Integer.parseInt(dateEnteredSplit[1]);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(dateEnteredSplit[2]);

    **System.out.println("day: " + day + "  month: " + month + "  year: " + year);**

    //The loop will be entered if any of the values are wrong. which will use recursion to call this method again for a chance to enter the date again.
    while (!(day >= 1 && day <= 31) || !(month >= 1 && month <= 12) || !(year > 1000 && year < 5000)) {
        **System.out.println("day: " + day + "  month: " + month + "  year: " + year);**
        //Im calling these methods to inform which one specifially was wrong so they know what they need to change.
        this.setDay(day);
        this.setMonth(month);
        this.setYear(year);

        dateEnteredSplit[0] = "0";
        askForDate(in);
    }

    //I then assign any correct value into the object attribute because the while loop is either finished or not entered at all. 
    //No need to use setDay etc. here because the checks have been done above in the while loop.
    this.day = day;
    this.month = month;
    this.year = year;  
}
```

Ok that is a method in a class. It asks for input in the format dd/mm/yyyy

If the first time I input 12/1/1996 it works, but if I enter a wrong date for example like this first, 123/123/123 and the enter a correct date for example 12/1/1996, it still enters the loop.

After debugging, the first line that is bold, the values are different from the second line that is bold, its like the values are changing by their own.

What is the problem here? I have been trying to find out in the past 1 hour.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like this is because of recursion. once they enter correct values your functions end call and then once you go back to the previous method the old values will be assigned. one dirty approach will be, return the correct values to previous function call

Comment: Don't use recursion to deal with invalid input, use a loop instead (ask for input until input is valid). Using recursion for that just creates problems and confusing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem very likely is in the way you are trying to combine recursive and iterative approach to update values (there is a while loop, that call the function recursively, which may also trigger while loop in next level of call and the previous one will continue calling itself recursively and you will end up with just mess)

There is no real reason to do that recursively, I would do iterative only approach, something like this:

```
public void askForDate(Scanner in) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the date that the vehicle entered the car park in this format dd/mm/yyyy :");

    int day, month, year;
    do { // We use do-while to get the first read without condition, although setting date to invalid value (like day = 0) and then running standard while loop will work just as fine
        String[] dateEnteredSplit = in.nextLine().split("/");

        //Assigning each element and converting them to integers.
        day = Integer.parseInt(dateEnteredSplit[0]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(dateEnteredSplit[1]);
        year = Integer.parseInt(dateEnteredSplit[2]);
    } while (!(day >= 1 && day <= 31) || !(month >= 1 && month <= 12) || !(year > 1000 && year < 5000));

    // Now day month and year variables are set correctly and we can do stuff with it
}
```

If you insist or recursive approach, the correct way would be to call the function just once:

```
public void askForDate(Scanner in) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the date that the vehicle entered the car park in this format dd/mm/yyyy :");

    int day, month, year;
    String[] dateEnteredSplit = in.nextLine().split("/");

    //Assigning each element and converting them to integers.
    day = Integer.parseInt(dateEnteredSplit[0]);
    month = Integer.parseInt(dateEnteredSplit[1]);
    year = Integer.parseInt(dateEnteredSplit[2]);

    if (!(day >= 1 && day <= 31) || !(month >= 1 && month <= 12) || !(year > 1000 && year < 5000)) askForDate(in);

    // You need to save day/month/year variables to other than local scope (like this.day = day)
    // Otherwise it would just somewhere in recursion stack and you wouldn't be able to use it
}
```

Just to be complete, keep in mind that date string could be wrong in other way that just number out of range. What if user types `1. 2. 3456` or `a/b/c` or not even something very different like `Hello`
At your snippet of code would crash (either throw `NumberFormatException` when trying to parse non-integer or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when accessing `dateEnteredSplit` array at element that doesnt exists (there are no '/' in 'Hello'))

Comment: John.... you are great. I was just suuuper over complicating it with absolute no reason. 

I had a gap in Java programming for 5 months where I didn't program at all, back then I think I would have gotten it, but now I have lost some of the basic techniques since the big gap. Any advice on how to get back on track?

I am a second year Software Engineer student.

Comment: Well, if you want to get better at something (like programming) just do that thing, try harder and harder problems and gain experience that way. If you are interested in algorithmic problems try [projecteuler](https://projecteuler.net/) or any other similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens. Wrong values on a first while loop iteration make a call to `askForDate` possible. You receive a second prompt and provide correct input. The second call of `askForDate` ends as expected. The execution returns again to a while loop, where you still have the first wrongly set values and the process starts again.

If you really do want to use recursion here, you should return a value from your function (dates or boolean flag) and check it in a while loop condition.